# Transition animation for imageview animationImages

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, transition

Hey I'm using animationImages method in my UIImageView and I was wondering if there is a way to add a transition animation to it?
I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation directly with UIImageView but there must be a way.

This is the code I'm already using:

```
image = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"slide1.png",@"slide2.png", @"slide3.png", @"slide4.png", @"slide5.png", @"slide6.png", @"slide7.png", @"slide8.png", @"slide9.png", nil];

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < image.count; i++) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[image objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    //slider = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    slider.animationImages = images;
    slider.animationDuration = 30;
    //slider.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [slider startAnimating];
```

Thanks in advance